# Calendaring daemon

Tags: calendar

I'm looking for a calendaring application that runs as a daemon, engages with the system eg starting applications or interacting with the desktop environment ( KDE ,Gnome ,E17, Lxde etc. ). I would like it to be able to sync with common calendaring applications probably via iCal but not being well versed in calendaring I'm not certain.

Comment: You should be more clear about what you want. The question discusses syncing with applications, but your response to an answer says that it should not sync. Do not confuse server processes with daemons. Daemons run in the background without user interaction (cron, httpd, sendmail, etc.). Even the X server is not a daemon - it does not run in the background - it is directly in front of you.  Your response also states that this _server_ should be started during boot, when there is no way to interact with a desktop environment; it could with applications. Clarify your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at Akonadi, the KDE personal information management storage system.

https://userbase.kde.org/Akonadi

`akonadi-calendar-tools` contains `konsolekalendar`, a CLI application which allows accessing calendar data.